# Oracle UNISTR in SQL and PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

When I execute below query in SQL and in PL/SQL (stored procedure), both gives different results. Why is that?

Query: `select UNISTR('\03A6') from dual;`

Sql outputs `Φ` where as PL/SQL outputs `F`

I am using sql developer to execute both.

How can I make pl/sql return `Φ`

Comment: Something to do with the NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS, give it a search I don't recall now to give you a proper answer.

Comment: Can you please try them with single quotes? `select UNISTR('\03A6') from dual;`

Comment: Sorry. I had tried with single quotes but my post was incorrect. Edited the post. So the inconsistency I see is with the single quotes.

Comment: What is your database character set (`NLS_CHARACTERSET` and `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET`)? Which tool do you use? (SQL*Plus, TOAD, SQL Developer, ...) What is your local `NLS_LANG` value?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, I use SQL Developer. Character sets are: `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET = AL16UTF16
NLS_CHARACTERSET = WE8MSWIN1252`

Answer (score 0):

Function [UNISTR](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions240.htm#SQLRF06154) expects a string as input parameter. Usually you should get error

`ORA-00911: invalid character`

when you run `UNISTR(\03A6)`

Try `select UNISTR('\03A6') from dual;` instead.

Comment: Sorry. I had tried with single quotes but my post was incorrect. Edited the post. So the inconsistency I see is with the single quotes.